# Compile time support for Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, autofac, strong-typing

We investigate DI containers for our project. Right now we choose between Autofac and Castle Windsor. There is something that is very important for us: Strongly type registration for Autofac.

Example:

```
public interface ITestAutofac
{        
}

public class NotDerivedFrom
{        
}
```

For the Windsor I can write something like this -

```
var cont = new WindsorContainer();

cont.Register(Component
    .For<ITestAutofac>().ImplementedBy<NotDerivedFrom>());
```

And it will be failed by compile time. Resharper can easily helps in this.

For the Autofac I can write like this -

```
builder.Register(c => new NotDerivedFrom()).As<ITestAutofac>();

var form = container.Resolve<ICustomForm>();
```

And it will fail at runtime.

How can I register types in Autofac with compile time checking?

Answer (score 4):

```cs
builder.Register<NotDerivedFrom>().As<ITestAutofac>()
```

With Autofac this will fail at runtime when, but this will happen when you call `builder.Build()` which is not really bad when you think about this. I agree, it's not as nice as having compile-time support, but you can find a unit test that calls `builder.Build()`. Don't forget that most DI configuration errors can never be caught by the compiler anyway and you need your container, [a verifiable configuration](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-to#Verifying_Configuration), and a some unit tests to find all configuration errors.

> How can I register types in Autofac with compile time checking?

If you wish, you can write a simple extension method that adds compile time checking:

```cs
public static void Register<TService, TImplementation>(
    this ContainerBuilder builder)
    // Note the generic type constraints here
    where TImplementation: class, TService
    where TService: class
{
    builder.Register<TImplementation>().As<TService>();
}
```

This allows you to do your original registration as follows:

```cs
build.Register<ITestAutofac, NotDerivedFrom>();
```

Which will fail at compile time.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I wanted to say that compile-time support allow avoid stupid errors and for instance, castle and unity have this opportunity. Extension is a crutch in designing therefore I was interested in something "native" in autofac.

Comment: With Autofac you will this support at runtime. The configuration is verified the moment you call `builder.Build()`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Steven's answer I have updated the extension method to return the `IRegistrationBuilder` to enable one to continue working with the registration (setting scope etc):

```
public static class ContainerBuilderExtensions
{
  public static IRegistrationBuilder<TImplementation, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>
    RegisterType<TService, TImplementation>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
    where TImplementation : class, TService
    where TService : class
  {
    return builder.RegisterType<TImplementation>().As<TService>();
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<IMyFactory, MyFactory>().SingleInstance();
var container = builder.Build();
```